# Implementing vector type in C

Tags: c

I'm implementing my own vector type, but because I do not want to always pass reference to functions `(&v)`, so I tried to define a pointer type to my vector structure. I simply have the following code which throws segmentation fault:

```
typedef struct vector {
    void **items;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int size;
} vector_st;

typedef vector_st * vector_t;

void vector_init(vector_t v, unsigned int capacity)
{
    v = (vector_t)calloc(1, sizeof(vector_st)); // even using this throws segmentation fault;
    v->capacity = capacity;
    v->size = 0;
    v->items = malloc(sizeof(void *) * v->capacity);
    if (v->items == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static void vector_resize(vector_t v, unsigned int capacity)
{
    void **items = realloc(v->items, sizeof(void *) * capacity);
    if (items) {
        v->items = items;
        v->capacity = capacity;
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void vector_add(vector_t v, void *item)
{
    if (v->capacity == v->size) {
        vector_resize(v, v->capacity * 2);
    }
    v->items[v->size++] = item;
}

unsigned int vector_capacity(vector_t v)
{
    return v->capacity;
}

unsigned int vector_size(vector_t v)
{
    return v->size;
}

void vector_free(vector_t v)
{
    if (v) {
        free(v->items);
        v = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector_t v;
    vector_init(v, 4);

    vector_add(v, "Hello");
    vector_add(v, "from");
    vector_add(v, "the");
    vector_add(v, "hole");

    printf("Vector capacity: %u\n", vector_capacity(v));
    printf("Vector size: %u\n", vector_size(v));

    vector_free(v);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that this is kind of a general question, but I cannot seem to figure out where the memory error is occurring, while even if I call `calloc` inside the `vector_init` function the segmentation fault occurs again.

If I just define the type as `typedef vector_st vector_t`, meaning without as pointer type, and then define functions as accepting pointer, and pass them references as `&v`, then it works okay, but as I said my goal is to avoid using `&` when calling functions.

Comment: Sidenote: C does not support references. And please read [ask]. And **never ever** `typedef` a pointer!

Comment: Changing the question after accepting an answer creates a confusing post.  Post rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main function you are declaring an uninitialized pointer and passing it to the vector_init function. Then you are trying to dereference the pointer, which is null or garbage. You need to allocate the memory for the vector first (not just allocate memory for the items).

```
vector_t vector = (vector_t)malloc(sizeof(vector_st));
```

[update]

Normally, I write something equivalent to,

```
vector_t vector_init(unsigned int capacity) {
    vector_t v;

    v = (vector_t)calloc(1, sizeof(vector_st));
    v->capacity = capacity;
    v->size = 0;
    v->items = malloc(sizeof(void*) * capacity);
    if(v->items == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Or, because you requested the "by reference" example,

```
void vector_init(vector_t *u, unsigned int capacity) {   
    vector_t v;

    v = *u;

    v = (vector_t)calloc(1, sizeof(vector_st));
    v->capacity = capacity;
    v->size = 0;
    v->items = malloc(sizeof(void*) * capacity);
    if(v->items == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I would strongly advise against the latter: it requires you to check that the vector was not originally allocated, and to handle the case if it was allocated.

Comment: I have `calloc` inside my `vector_init` function though. It still throws segmengation fault. But, using your approach does not. I basically do not want to initialize it inside main, but do that via functions.

Comment: Sorry, I think you uncommented the code just as I answered :) The problem is that you are passing the pointer by value. So pointer variable is only modified locally in the function. To get the newly allocated vector back you have to pass the pointer by reference, use a **, or return the pointer from the function.

Comment: Thanks, I switched to returning the pointer from the function and it seems to work fine. If you can write the first approach meaning passing the pointer by reference as an answer here as an alternative method, I can accept it.

Comment: Unsolicited advice: don't avoid using &. It is a useful little flag for someone reading the code that you are going to return a different object to what is passed in.